# Copy file from node_modules in a dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, nvm

I've **module A** with the following `postinstall` script:

```
"postinstall": "cp node_modules/dep-module/file.txt lib/file.txt"
```

After running `npm install` the file can be found and copied:

```
module-A
|- node_modules
   |- dep-module
      |- file.txt
```

This worked fine until I imported the **module A** from the **module B**:

```
"module-a": "0.0.1"
```

Now since I do the `npm install` from module B the dir structure is:

```
module-B
|- node_modules
   |- module-A
   |- dep-module
      |- file.txt
```

The `file.txt` cannot be find in the same route, it should be instead:

```
"postinstall": "cp ../dep-module/file.txt lib/file.txt"
```

**What are the best options here to solve this issue?**

Currently I've hacked a script that simple does a path check to see if there is a `node_modules` dir, but I would prefer a solution where I can avoid the node script...

```
const getModulePath = module =>
  fs.existsSync(path.resolve('./node_modules')) ? `./node_modules/${module}` : `../${module}`;

fs.copy(`${getModulePath('dep-module')}/file.txt`, 'dist/file.txt');
```

Comment: You could run a Node script that does `require.resolve('dep-module/file.txt')`

Comment: @SLaks exactly. I've done done, but I was searching for a solution that didn't require an external script... if there is any. I'll add my current solution.

Comment: oh, not quite what I've done... just noticed the `resolve` there! Either way I still need the node script for this, right?

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for! Now I can run on `postinstall`: `"postinstall": "cp \`node -p "require.resolve('dep-module/file.txt')"\` ./lib/file.txt"`

Comment: @SLaks if you mind to propose an answer so I can close this one it would be super

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `require.resolve()` to resolve a module-style string to a file path.